# a,b element of a set imply that a and b are distinct elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On a homework assignment, I was given the following definition of a set.
[image]

I thought the teacher had made a typo. I believe according to the conditions given,
T ={"*"} because condition 2 would be trivially satisfied if a set had only one element. My friend said, it applies because there is the possibility that t1 = t2. I thought that made no sense. Could someone please shed some light on this set?

Comment: The examples are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no typo and your friend is right. In fact, (2) could be rewritten as

> for all $t_1, t_2 \in \cal{T}$, one has $(t_1t_2) \in \cal{T}$

which includes the particular case $t_1 = t_2$.

Comment: Would that mean that $((**) (**))$ is also in t because you could let t1 =t2 = (**)?

Comment: Well, $()$ is not supposed to be in $\cal{T}$. If you apply the second rule with $t_1 = t_2 = (**)$, you get the element $((**)(**))$, not $(()())$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry it got formatted wrong the first time. Thanks!